# Sums of Column A values for contigious same-value boolean values of separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 3), columns=list('ACD'))
df['C > D'] = df['C'] > df['D']

    A            C          D           C > D
0   0.031469    0.104515    0.123596    False
1   0.549081    0.065270    0.036311    True
2   0.426498    0.674991    0.601090    True
3   0.759211    0.680903    0.601398    True
4   0.459308    0.801639    0.572331    True
5   0.691453    0.559478    0.959135    False
6   0.181677    0.091478    0.192358    False
7   0.186661    0.981368    0.721595    True
8   0.473044    0.603869    0.683941    False
9   0.015301    0.173707    0.304635    False
10  0.645700    0.300221    0.944034    False
11  0.087918    0.020047    0.720342    False
12  0.012420    0.017378    0.050286    False
13  0.496994    0.631002    0.618231    True
14  0.133083    0.454531    0.451067    True
```

### What I am attempting to do:

I am trying to create a new column, that will
take the sum of `Column A` in relation to contiguous same-valued groups of column C>D.

So the first value of C>D is `False` and there aren't any `False` values afterwards, so this contiguous same-valued group consists of one item, and the return values are the sum of all elements from Column A that fall into this group (index 0), `0.031469`

The next group due to change of value (from False to True) consist of indices 1-4 (inclusive), which hold all True values.
So the values for this group would be the sum of:

```
1   0.549081    
2   0.426498    
3   0.759211    
4   0.459308
```

which is something like `2.201` (at the top of my head).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contiguous same values can be identified with `cumsum()` on non-zero differences. So you can do:

```
# print groups to see details
groups = df['C > D'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

# groupby
df.groupby(gropus)['A'].sum()
```

Output:

```
C > D
1    0.031469
2    2.194098
3    0.873130
4    0.186661
5    1.234383
6    0.630077
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Quang, just a quick question regarding ne(0). Is this in order to have the 'nan' value represented as a group?

Comment: ne stands for 'not equal', when chained with diff will detects those rows where values change. Then we chain with 'cumsum' for block detection.

Comment: Hi Quang. What I meant to say was, doesn't diff automatically detect those changes? I was playing around with your code, but just using `diff` produces same output (unless I am making a mistake):|
`df['groups'] = df[' C>D'].diff().bfill().cumsum()`
`df.groupby('groups')['A'].sum()`